# How to effectively get an US AltGr-Intl layout on NetBSD?

Tags: keyboard-layout, netbsd

After switching to the us layout with `wsconsctl -w encoding=us` I was looking for a way to modify the keymap to my liking.

I did:

```
wsconsctl -w map+="keycode 1 = Cmd_Debugger Caps_Lock"
wsconsctl -w map+="keycode 58 = Escape"
```

to swap caps lock and escape keys (I'm a Vim user, so this kind of swap makes sense).

I noticed `wsconsctl map` set `keycode 184 = Mode_switch Multi_key`, which as far as I understand, is the function you get with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> on a German keyboard, for instance.

I tried setting keycode 184 to `Mode_switch` (it's normally set to `Alt_R`, which does nothing for me), but I do't exactly get the functionality of <kbd>AltGr</kbd> it seems.

Since NetBSD doesn't seem to come with a US AltGr-Intl variant, I though of defining at least *some* of the keys I need (which are German umlauts, for instance) myself, and "backport" the AltGr-Intl variant that way.

So the first thing I tried was `wsconsctl -w map+="keycode 16 = q Q adiaeresis Adiaeresis"`

When I do that, I get weird error codes on the console, when typing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>:  `<00ef>` looks like a utf-8 code or something similar to me. Anyway it's not producing an 'ä', as I'd expect.
Also, when checking what's in the keymap now, after having it changed, this is what happens:

```
# wsconsctl map | grep -i "code 16"
keycode 16 = q Q adiaeresis gr_D
```

"`gr_D`"? Where did that come from? For some reason `wsconsctl` seems to dislike `Adiaeresis` even though it's in `/usr/include/dev/wscons/wsksymdef.h` line 192:

```
#define    KS_Adiaeresis    0xc4
```

I noticed that it doesn't happen with every character.
I tried mapping `wsconsctl -w map+="keycode 16 = q Q at at"` and that works fine. After that, I can type a '@', by hitting <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>.

Also, When I'm at the login prompt, I can type special characters by holding down <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, entering `äåéóöëíúáßðfø¶œï` as a user name is no problem, but once I log in, it seems to load the us encoding, and I just have a plain US layout from then on.

Basically, the idea is to be able to enter special (latin) characters by holding down <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, or right Alt.

The OS is NetBSD 7.0/amd64 running in a VM on an amd64 host (Linux).